# Toggle show/hide to a specific element

Tags: reactjs

I have this particular code that shows a list of questions and buttons for each of it. When I click the button, it will show the specific answer to the question. My problem is, I have a bunch of questions and when i click the button, it will show all of the answer instead of the specific answer to that question.

Here is the code

```
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
                  answer: [],
                  isHidden: true
               }
  this.toggleHidden = this.toggleHidden.bind(this)
}

componentWillMount(){
  fetch('http://www.reddit.com/r/DrunkOrAKid/hot.json?sort=hot')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then( (data) => {
      const answer = data.data.children.map(obj => obj.data);
      this.setState({answer});
     })
 }

toggleHidden(){
  this.setState({isHidden: !this.state.isHidden})
}

render(){
    const answer = this.state.answer.slice(2)
    return <div>
             <h1>Drunk or Kid</h1>
             {answer.map(answer =>
              <div key={answer.id}>
                <p className="title">{answer.title}</p>
                <button onClick={this.toggleHidden}>Answer</button>
                {!this.state.isHidden && <Show>{answer.selftext}</Show>}
               </div>
             )}
           </div>
  }
}
const Show = (props) => <p className="answer">{props.children}</p>
```

And here is the link to the [codepen](http://codepen.io/mdchad/pen/BpzgQg?editors=1010)

Comment: All of the answers are sharing the same piece of `isHidden` state. So, when you toggle that state boolean, all of them show. You would have to isolate the `isHidden` state for each answer in order to have them independently toggle. Since React is designed to be component based, I suggest making a component for each question/answer combination with the `isHidden` state in each and map over that data to create an instance for each.

Comment: I found a good tutorial in case you want to learn more: https://noobieprogrammer.blogspot.com/2020/09/reactjs-how-to-create-toggle-showhide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BpQNEP?editors=1010) based on my suggestion:

The basics of the child component would be:

```
class Question extends React.Component {
  // Set initial state of isHidden to false
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isHidden: false
    }
  }
  // Toggle the visibility
  toggleHidden() {
    this.setState({
      isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
    });
  }
  // Render the component
  render() {
    const { answer } = this.props;
    return (
      <div key={answer.id}>
        <p className="title">{answer.title}</p>
        <button onClick={ () => this.toggleHidden() }>Answer</button>
        {this.state.isHidden && <Show>{answer.selftext}</Show>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then you would map over it within the parent component as:

```
answer.map(answer =>
    <Question answer={answer} key={answer.id} />
)
```

Comment: `<button onClick={ () => this.toggleHidden() }>Answer</button>` Why do you you put a callback here instead of just `onClick=this.toggleHidden` ? In my original code,the `onClick=this.toggleHidden` toggle works but when I tried to paste it in inside your code, it says cannot set setState of undefined ? Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @Irsyad14 You have to add back the binding in the constructor. I just was writing a solution, quickly. `this.toggleHidden = this.toggleHidden.bind(this)`

Comment: Now I got it. Silly me. I'm kinda new to react. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add a state that save opened answer id, then checking if specific answer in that state or not.

let's see in action

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            opened: []
        }
        this.toggleShowHide = this.toggleShowHide.bind(this)
    }
    toggleShowHide(e){
        const id = parseInt(e.currentTarget.dataset.id)
        if (this.state.opened.indexOf(id) != -1){
            // remove from array
            this.setState({opened: this.state.opened.filter(o => o !== id)})
        } else {
            this.setState({opened: [...this.state.opened, id]})
        }
    }
    render(){
        return <ul>
            { this.state.answers.map(ans => (
                <li key={ans.id} data-id={ans.id}>
                    question 
                    <button onClick={this.toggleShowHide}>show answer</button>
                    <span
                     style={{ display: this.state.opened.indexOf(ans.id) !== -1 ? 'block' : 'none' }}>answer</span>
                </li>
             ))}
       </ul>
    }
}
```

Here is video in action https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJsPEsckB4w